# Функция вызывается несколько раз

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gorborukov/0722a93c35dfba96337b/raw/435b297ac6d90d13a68935e1ec7a69a225969e58/russia')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok (${response.status} ${response.statusText})`);
    }
    return response.json();
  })

  .then(jsonData => {
    const regions = jsonData.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc.push(item.region);
      return acc;
    }, [])
    const listRegions = [...new Set(regions)]
    return JsonRegion(listRegions)
  })

export default function JsonRegion(listRegions) {
  const listItems = Object.values(listRegions).map(region => <option>{region}</option>);
  return <select>{listItems}</select>;
}
```

Начал изучать React, хочу получить список областей России, а после вставить в html, но функция обрабатывается три раза и возвращает пустой список listItems. Хотя при первом вызове ListItems заполнен.

Comment: Ну, как минимум реакт каждый свой элемент два раза вызывает, есть такое. А как вы передаёте `listRegions` в `JsonRegion`? Используете ли `useState` для хранения этой переменной в компоненте (это очень жирный намёк, где проблема). А, так вы вообще этот компонент напрямую вызываете с параметром, а не встраиваете как `JSX` элемент? Очень интересный подход.

Comment: Покажите компонент полностью. Сейчас не понято, где работает ваш fetch